# Save non AscII characters python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, non-ascii-characters

I make script to extract some data from pdf files and later save in excel file.

When I convert pdf file to text I no have problem with non ASCII characters but when I save into excel file don't work good.

This my code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO
import os
import xlsxwriter

import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')


# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('zzzzz.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:

    z = 0

e = (len(files) - 1)



def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    fstr = ''
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,    password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

        str = retstr.getvalue()
        fstr += str

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return fstr

row = 0
col = 0

while z<e:    

    factura = files[z]
    #ejemplo 1

    string = convert_pdf_to_txt(factura)
    lines = list(filter(bool,string.split('\n')))
    custData = {}
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if 'EMAIL:' in lines[i]:
            custData['Name'] = lines[i+1]
        elif 'FACTURA' in lines[i]:
            custData['BillNumber'] = lines[i+1]
        elif 'Vencimientos:' in lines[i]:
            custData['price'] = lines[i+2]
        elif 'Banco:' in lines[i]:
            custData['paymentType'] = lines[i+1]
            if custData['paymentType'] == "Vencimientos:":
                custData['paymentType'] = lines[i-2]



    #ejemplo 2
    txtList = convert_pdf_to_txt(factura).splitlines()
    nameIdx, billNumIdx, priceIdx, expirDateIdx, paymentIdx = -1, -1, -1, -1, -1

    for idx, line in enumerate(txtList):
        if line == "EMAIL: buendialogistica@gmail.com":
            nameIdx = idx +2 # in your example it should be +2...

        if line == "FACTURA":
            billNumIdx = idx + 1

        if "Vencimientos:" in line:
            priceIdx = idx + 2
            expirDateIdx = idx + 1

        if "Banco:" in line:
            paymentIdx = idx + 1

    name = txtList[nameIdx] if nameIdx != -1 else ''
    billNum = txtList[billNumIdx] if billNumIdx != -1 else ''
    price = txtList[priceIdx] if priceIdx != -1 else ''
    expirDate = txtList[expirDateIdx] if expirDateIdx != -1 else ''
    payment = txtList[paymentIdx] if paymentIdx != -1 else ''


    print expirDate

    billNum = billNum.replace("Â Â ", "")


    print billNum


    custData['Name'] = custData['Name'].replace("Â", "")

    print custData['Name']


    custData['paymentType'] = custData['paymentType'].replace("Â", "")

    print custData['paymentType']

    print price
    nombre = str(custData['Name'])



    formadepago = custData['paymentType']

    z+=1
    columna2 = str(billNum) + ", " + nombre + ", " + formadepago



    worksheet.write(row, col, expirDate)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, columna2) 
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, price)
    row+=1

workbook.close()
```

This the errors I have now:

```
FRECH ESPAÑA S.A.U. = FRECH ESPAÃ‘A S.A.U.

MONTSERRAT CARRIÓ KÖTZ - LA FUSTERIA = MONTSERRAT CARRIÃ“ KÃ–TZ - LA FUSTERIA.
```

I try many code for work with non-ASCII character but I'm not able to make any work.

The only variable in my code can have non-ASCII characters are "nombre"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please minimize your code in order to remove unneeded parts and fix the styling? Your code seems to contain a lot of parts which are not necessary for reproducing your problem.

Comment: FWIW, `# -*- coding: ` directives do **not** affect how your script processes text, they just tell the interpreter what encoding has been used to create the script itself. Also, only the first encoding directive has any effect. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: I guess you're working with Python 2.x, have you tried with Python 3?

Comment: Or try to decode to UTF-8? `print 'FRECH ESPAÑA S.A.U.'.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')`

Comment: Remove `reload(sys) ; sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')` - It's going to mask all kinds of encoding issues.